# Is there a Swift Array equivalent for NSArray.arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray()?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsarray

I would like to gain a new array by appending elements to an existing array without modifying it. `NSArray` has `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray()`, e.g.:

```
let numbers = (["one", "two", "three"] as NSArray).arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray(["four", "five"]) as! [String]
```

Is there an equivalent for Swift's `Array` struct that would make bridging to `NSArray` unnecessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you looking for this one? Your existing array does not modify.

```
let existingArray = ["four", "five"]
let numbers = ["one", "two", "three"] + existingArray
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like this. Brillant how clean it is in Swift now.

Comment: Love to play with Swift :)